# How to display the string variable in the root using Spark SQL?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Long story short - I am using a spark code in Scala IDE to convert json to csv. I don't have knowledge about spark as I have worked only on RDBMS like Oracle, TD and DB2. All I was given was, the code which will converts the json data to csv and how to pass the arguments to retrieve data from the schema.

Now, I am able to fetch the data which is inside a struct and array by using

```
val val1 = df.select(explode($"data.business").as("ID")).select($"ID.amountTO")
 val1.repartition(1).write.format("com.databricks.spark.csv").option("header", "true").save(args(2) + "\\Result" + "\\" + timeForpath + "\\val1")
```

I don't know to export the columns which are not in the struct and are directly in the root of the schema like QAYONOutCome, QA1PartiesComments etc..

```
root
 |-- QAYONOutCome: string (nullable = true)
 |-- QA1PartiesComments: string (nullable = true)
 |-- QA1PartiesQID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- QA1PartiesResponse: string (nullable = true)
 |-- QAHolderTypeComments: string (nullable = true)
 |-- QAHolderTypeQID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- QAHolderTypeResponse: string (nullable = true)
 |-- QAhighRiskComments: string (nullable = true)
 |-- QAhighRiskQID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- QAhighRiskResponse: string (nullable = true)
 |-- QA2ClassComments: string (nullable = true)
 |-- QA2ClassQID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- QA2ClassResponse: string (nullable = true)
 |-- QAoutcomeComments: string (nullable = true)
 |-- QAoutcomeQID: string (nullable = true)
 |-- QAoutcomeResponse: string (nullable = true)
 |-- data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- business: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- amountTO: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- ID: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- Registration: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- country: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- line1: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- line2: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- postCode: string (nullable = true)
```

Any help is appreciated. Apologies if my question sounds very dumb :(. Please let me know if some more information is needed to provide a solution or clarity. Thanks much in advance.

Comment: your code looks good you should just keep selecting all the required cols as you already did with `select($"ID.amountTO", $"ID. ID", $"ID. Registration. country" ...)`

Comment: How to export the columns which are not in the struct and are directly in the root of the schema like QAYONOutCome, QA1PartiesComments?

Comment: with spark selectors as shown above `select($"ID.amountTO", $"ID. ID", $"ID.Registration.country" etc)`

Comment: Thanks @AlexandrosBiratsis .. I wrote the below code and it worked. Thanks a lot for your response.

`val test = df.select ($"QAYONOutCome",$"QA1PartiesComments")
test.show()`

I was co-relating it for the missing 'from' condition as in SQL scripts and was making errors earlier.